# Have some problems with youtube resumable uploader

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, youtube, google-drive-api

I want to transfer my videos from google drive to youtube using following script in **google apps script**:

```
    function myFunction() {
      // Please set the file ID of video file and the metadata for uploading it to YouTube.
      const fileId = "###";
      const metadata = {
        snippet: { description: "Upload sample.", title: "Sample uploaded video." },
        status: { privacyStatus: "private" },
      };
    
      // 1. Retrieve location.
      const headers = { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() };
      const url1 = encodeURI(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet,status"
      );
      const res1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, {
        headers,
        payload: JSON.stringify(metadata),
        contentType: "application/json",
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
      });
      if (res1.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        console.log(res1.getContentText());
        return;
      }
      const location = res1.getAllHeaders()["Location"];
      console.log("Got Location.");
    
      // 2. Calculate chunks.
      const chunkSize = 20971520; // 20 MB
      const { fileSize } = Drive.Files.get(fileId, {
        supportsAllDrives: true,
        fields: "fileSize",
      });
      const chunks = [...Array(Math.ceil(fileSize / chunkSize))].map((_, i, a) => [
        i * chunkSize,
        i == a.length - 1 ? fileSize - 1 : (i + 1) * chunkSize - 1,
      ]);
      console.log("Calculated chunk data.");
    
      // 3. Retrieve chunks from Google Drive with the partial download and uploading chunks to YouTube with the resumable upload.
      const url2 = `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileId}?alt=media&supportsAllDrives=true`;
      let res2;
      const len = chunks.length;
      chunks.forEach((e, i) => {
        console.log(`Now... ${i + 1}/${len}`);
        const params2 = {
          headers: {
            authorization: headers.authorization,
            range: `bytes=${e[0]}-${e[1]}`,
          },
        };
        res2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, params2).getContent();
        const params3 = {
          headers: { "Content-Range": `bytes ${e[0]}-${e[1]}/${fileSize}` },
          payload: res2,
          muteHttpExceptions: true,
        };
        console.log("Downloaded a chunk, and upload a chunk.");
        const res3 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(location, params3);
        const statusCode = res3.getResponseCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
          console.log("Done.");
          console.log(res3.getContentText());
        } else if (statusCode == 308) {
          console.log("Upload the next chunk.");
          res2.splice(0, res2.length);
        } else {
          throw new Error(res3.getContentText());
        }
      });
    
      // Please don't remove the following comment line. This comment line is important for running this script.
      // YouTube.Videos.insert(); // This is used for automatically detecting the scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube" with the script editor.
    }
```

**this script work with google drive api and youtube api v3.**
but this script have some problems and limitions.

1. I can't select the source Google Drive account and the destination
   YouTube channel for upload the video separately. for example in
   following sample i must select @gmail account as Google Drive
   account video file source and script must upload video file from
   google drive account to youtube channel (youtube account) but when i
   select @gmail account, script upload video file to @gmail youtube
   channel and not upload to my youtube account. if i select youtube
   account then script can't read file from google drive! How to fix this problem?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4o80.jpg

2. In the current stage, the **maximum execution time of Google Apps
   Script is 6 minutes** and i can't upload large video files. i get
   **exceeded maximum execution time** error. also i don't know how to executing the script with the **time-driven trigger** and how to fix this? **if i use time-driven trigger** for executing this script then i must apply some changes in this script, what is changes that i must apply?
3. after executing script when i check my youtube channel, i encounter
   the following scene. **multiple upload processing!** How to fix it??

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PYxD.jpg

How to fix this problems?

Comment: @tanaike sir, can you fix this problems with your code?

Comment: I don't know how or where you get this code, but, try to separate the logic in functions, then, check how you can improve this code. Try to divide and handle each problem separately.